# Send multiple array in parameter in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm calling a service in which I'm trying to send parameter that consist of array within an array and other parameters which are outside from an array. The format in which I have to send parameter is this:

```
{
"RestID": 0,
"cart": [
{
  "childs": [
    {
      "addon_cat_id": 0,
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "next_move_id": 0,
      "price": 0,
      "sort_order": 0,
      "type": "string"
    }
  ],
  "name": "string",
  "price": "string",
  "productid": 0,
  "qty": 0,
  "description": "string"
}
],
"coupon_code": "string",
"coupon_type": "string",
"coupon_value": 0,
"delivery_price": "string",
"discount_amount": "string"
}
```

This is how I'm sending my parameter in the service:

```
 let parameter:[String:Any] = ["RestID":restaurantId!,
                                  "cart":[["childs":["addon_cat_id":"0",

                                                     "id":ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemId!,
                                                     "name":ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemName!,
                                                     "next_move_id":"",
                                                     "price":ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemPrice!,
                                                     "sort_order":"",
                                                     "type":"string"

                                    ]],
                                          ["name": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemName!,
                                            "price": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemPrice!,
                                            "productid": ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemId!,
                                            "qty": 2,
                                            "description":ItemDataSource.sharedInstance.items[0].itemDdescription!]
                                        ],
                                  "coupon_code" : couponCode!,
                                  "coupon_type" : couponType!,
                                  "coupon_value" : couponValue!,
                                  "delivery_price" : deliveryLbl.text!,
                                  "discount_amount" : disocunt!,
                                  "discount_description" : discountDesc!,
                                  "discount_info" : discountInfo!,
                                  "distance": "",
                                  "door_num" : doorTxt.text!,
                                  "firstname" : "",
                                  "lastname" : "",
                                  "order_type" : "Delivery",
                                  "payment_mode" : "",
                                  "phone" : mobileTxt.text!,
                                  "postcode" : postCodeTxt.text!,
                                  "preorder" : true,
                                  "preorder_is_preorder" : "",
                                  "street" : address1Txt.text!,
                                  "token" : "",
                                  "town" : addressTxt2.text!,
                                  "total": self.grandTotalLbl.text!,
                                  "stripeToken" : "",
                                  "customer_id" : "2",
                                  "preordertime": preOrderTime,
                                  "usercmt": "descri",
                                  "email": userEmail!
                                     ]
```

But when I call the service I get an error. I have discussed this with the server side and they are saying it is a mistake in sending the parameter. How can I send multiple arrays within an array in parameter?

This is my service class:

```
class SaveOrderDeliveryService{
    static let instance = SaveOrderDeliveryService()
    var status:Int = 0

    func saveOrderDelivery(param:[String:Any],completion:@escaping CompletionHandler)  {
        Alamofire.request(saveOrderDeliveryUrl, method: .post, parameters:param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print("Result: \(response.result)")// response serialization result
            print(response)

            if response.result.error == nil{
                self.status = (response.response?.statusCode)!
                if(self.status == 200){
                    print(response)
                    guard let data = response.data else {return}
                    do{
                        if let json = try JSON(data: data).dictionary{
                            completion(true)
                        }
                    }catch let jsonErr{
                        print(jsonErr)
                    }
                }

                completion(true)
            }else{
                completion(false)
                debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code used to send the data. You need to post details about the error. Please [edit] your question with all needed details.

Comment: there is no error in code but when i send request it shows response ur parameter are not submitted and status code 404. @rmaddy

Comment: is my parameter sending technique correct? is this according to the above given format? @rmaddy

Comment: The double bracket `]]` around line 11 of the snippet where you create `parameter`  seems to close your array of children before the second child. Either that or the thing that begins directly after it shouldn't be enclosed in its own `[`?

Comment: An error of 404 means "not found". This indicates the URL (`saveOrderDeliveryUrl`) isn't correct.

Comment: The scenario is that the parameter start with curly brackets and inside it is an array of name cart and inside cart there is another array of child , first the child close and than cart array close afterwards the curly brackets close. @Samantha

Comment: i think its parameter sending format is incorrect. @rmaddy

Comment: can u show how can i send it? @rmaddy

Comment: Your parameter structure is different from the format. Look at array in cart.

Comment: what could be the correct way u think to show like that? @HMHero

Comment: @raheem The params in Abdelahad Darwish's answer looks correct.

Comment: But still it isn't getting the correct response. @HMHero

Comment: The API is in ASP.net and i have tested in swagger where it is showing correct response but when i send the request from my app with the same format it shows not submitted response. @HMHero

Comment: i have tested the API in postman there i'm also getting the same 404 error. @HMHero

Answer (score 0):

Try this add your data , make sure now one with nil

```
    let parameters = [
        "RestID": "",
        "cart": [
            [
                "childs": [
                    [
                        "addon_cat_id": "",
                        "id": "",
                        "name": "string",
                        "next_move_id": "",
                        "price": "",
                        "sort_order": "",
                        "type": "string"
                    ]
                ],
                "name": "string",
                "price": "string",
                "productid": "",
                "qty": "",
                "description": "string"
            ]
        ],
        "coupon_code": "string",
        "coupon_type": "string",
        "coupon_value": "",
        "delivery_price": "string",
        "discount_amount": "string"
        ] as [String : Any]


    Alamofire.request(saveOrderDeliveryUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

    }
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed/fixed.

Comment: there is nothing to explain may be he write wrong parameter i set placeholder for his parameter  to give us what error he have after testing this

Comment: let me test this. @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: But how is what you posted different from what is in the question? That is what needs to be explained. Did you fix a typo somewhere? What exactly?

Comment: i have tested it still i'm getting the same error 404 parameter not submitted.@AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: we need more info print parameter before you send

Comment: ["coupon_value": "20", "delivery_price": "0", "firstname": "", "coupon_code": "hamza123", "lastname": "", "stripeToken": "", "discount_description": " has been detucted from whole cart", "payment_mode": "", "postcode": "sr47jp", "order_type": "Delivery", "town": "sdfsdf", "usercmt": "descri", "cart": [["description": "item desc", "name": "item1", "productid": "1012", "childs": [["next_move_id": "", "name": "item1", "id": "1012", "sort_order": "", "type": "string", "price": "785", "addon_cat_id": "0"]], "price": "785", "qty": 2]],"preorder": true, "RestID": "1003"]

Comment: this is how it is showing parameters in console .@AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: make sure you write correct URL , try use poster like post man , or send me url in private Message

Comment: url is correct i have checked it but still getting same error. I haven't posted the whole parameters bcz its quite long list just shown u guys the format , bcz i think it might be cause of parameter sending format. @AbdelahadDarwish

Comment: how i can privately message u? @AbdelahadDarwish